# Node Express server cannot be accessed through lan?

Tags: node.js, express

This question is a duplicate of many questions but nobody comes up with a different solution other than the accepted answer.
My node server works fine in my machine but cannot be accessed from other machines on LAN.

solutions  I tried

```
app.listen('80');

app.listen('80','0.0.0.0');

app.listen('80','mylocal-ip');
```

Nothing seems to be working.

Interestingly, **Apache server  works fine** in port 80 and can be accessed from all devices.This should mean there are no firewall issues right?

Any help?

Comment: @Aleksandr M Sorry,didn't get you.

Comment: What's the difference between `app.listen('80')` and `app.listen('80','0.0.0.0')` ?

Comment: @Aleksandr M app.listen('80') falls back to localhost thus cannot be accessed externally.

Comment: NO. Read - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback

Comment: I'm assuming you're not trying to run the Node.JS server and Apache server at the same time. What type of system are you running it on? Some firewalls, including Windows firewall, can be configured to allow specific applications, not necessarily just ports.

Comment: @ Aleksandr M Ok but either way this is not working.

Comment: @JoGoFo I tried running both within a span of minutes.But Didn't check for application specific firewalls.My machine is windows 8.